# How to group strings into different letter groups in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Goal: Group strings into into different letter groups.

Example letter groups: A to C, D to F, G to J, etc.

Pseudocode:

Loop through each group
  Loop through each string in a collection
    Print the string in the appropriate group

Question: What's the best way to define a range of characters so we can use something like the following to check?

[NSCharacterSet(our custom character range) characterIsMember:[self.targetString.text characterAtIndex:0] ]

Comment: Check the docs for the NSCharacterSet class.

Comment: I did and I know I can use [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:] but I want to see if anyone may be able to come up with more elegant solutions.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "group"? Can you include a input and output samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your character sets as follows for arbitrary ranges of ASCII characters:

```
NSCharacterSet *a_to_d_Set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange('a', 'd'-'a' + 1)];
NSCharacterSet *e_to_l_Set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange('e', 'l'-'e' + 1)];
```

Of course, you could equivalently write:

```
NSCharacterSet *a_to_d_Set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange('a', 4)];
```